# Login Failed after changing the password in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one online and desktop application build in c#. I can create new user from offline application and successfully using the same credential for online log in. But when I am changing password from offline its not affecting my online application. My online application is using ASP Membership table. After changing password I am not able to log in for online application, but if i used old password for online application log in, I am able to log in. Please suggest me what I am missing.

Comment: can you add the code snippet for the password change?

Comment: asuming your desktop app uses same db for data through some services...sounds like you might be checking login from online app against some session/cache instead of db. and that session/cache not being destroyed when password is updated. but, some code snippets would help

Comment: when i change password from offline application i can log in in offline application, but i am unable to log in online application. My online application is using ASP membership table.When i change password from online application i can log in offline application.

Comment: Online application is using validating password method of asp membership table. i am unable to figure out as when i change password from online everything works fine, but when i change password from offline i can log in in offline application but not for online application. My online application is still using my old password for log  in. Is there any problem with encryption when i am changing password with my offline application.

Comment: Hello everyone, I found the solution, actually when i was changing password from offline , it was making changes  in offline data tables but not for asp membership datatable.I just added 2 lines of code . Hope some one will benefit from it.                                               MembershipUser user =Membership.GetUser(DbConnect.gEmployeeCode);
  user.ChangePassword(user.ResetPassword(), tbNewPassword.Text);